# Angular ng-flow how to load files to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created couple of threads in stackoverflow before but seams that problem is in wrong usage of ng-flow. I need to send couple of parameters and images  and don't know how to upload them images to the server with other parameters  together in one request?

I have a form with two text fields and set of images that user can add with drag and drop using ng-flow. And I need to send them to server. Also I have a php service that ready to read those parameters and image.

How to write angular code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, more specifically, I was using a dynamic upload path. I know it is not best practice, but I solved it by adding a parameter to getParams: function()

```
        /**
         * Get params for a request
         * @function
         */
        getParams: function() {
            return {
                flowChunkNumber: this.offset + 1,
                flowChunkSize: this.flowObj.opts.chunkSize,
                flowCurrentChunkSize: this.endByte - this.startByte,
                flowTotalSize: this.fileObjSize,
                flowIdentifier: this.fileObj.uniqueIdentifier,
                flowFilename: this.fileObj.name,
                flowRelativePath: this.fileObj.relativePath,
                flowTotalChunks: this.fileObj.chunks.length,
                flowPath: <enter path variable here>
            };
        },
```